# Why is it allowed to put methods inside blocks, and statements inside objects in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala and I don't really understand the following example :

```scala
object Test extends App {

  def method1 = println("method 1")

  val x = {
    def method2 = "method 2" // method inside a block
    "this is " + method2
  }

  method1    // statement inside an object
  println(x) // same
}
```

I mean, it feels inconsistent to me because here I see two different concepts :

- Objects/Classes/Traits, which contains members.
- Blocks, which contains statements, the last statement being the value of the block.

But here we have a method part of a block, and statements part of an object. So, does it mean that blocks are objects too ? And how are handled the statements part of an object, are they members too ?

Thanks.

Comment: In scala functions are indeed objects. Read this [article](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/09/methods-functions.html) to understand the difference between functions and methods. Also "blocks" are sometimes necesary (and often convinient) to create complex algebraic structures and that is the reason they exist.

Comment: Thanks, I did understand the difference between functions and methods, but not why they can be defined inside blocks (not being members of objects/classes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that blocks are objects too?

No, blocks are not objects. Blocks are used for scoping the binding of variables. Scala enables not only defining expressions inside blocks but also to define methods. If we take your example and compile it, we can see what the compiler does:

```
object Test extends Object {
  def method1(): Unit = scala.Predef.println("method 1");

  private[this] val x: String = _;
  <stable> <accessor> def x(): String = Test.this.x;

  final <static> private[this] def method2$1(): String = "method 2";

  def <init>(): tests.Test.type = {
    Test.super.<init>();
    Test.this.x = {
      "this is ".+(Test.this.method2$1())
    };
    Test.this.method1();
    scala.Predef.println(Test.this.x());
    ()
  }
}
```

What the compiler did is extract `method2` to an "unnamed" method on `method2$1` and scoped it to `private[this]` which is scoped to the current instance of the type.

> And how are handled the statements part of an object, are they members
>   too?

The compiler took `method1` and `println` and calls them inside the constructor when the type is initialized. So you can see `val x` and the rest of the method calls are invoked at construction time.

Comment: Thanks ! How did you obtain this output ?

Comment: @TimothéeJourde You can peak into the compiler phases using `scalac -Xprint:<phase> filename`. You can view all phases via `scalac -Xshow-phases`.

Answer (score 1):

`method2` is actually not a method. It is a local function. Scala allows you to create named functions inside local scopes for organizing your code into functions without polluting the namespace.

It is most often used to define local tail-recursive helper functions. Often, when making a function tail-recursive, you need to add an additional parameter to carry the "state" on the call stack, but this additional parameter is a private internal implementation detail and shouldn't be exposed to clients. In languages without local functions, you would make this a `private` helper *alongside* the primary method, but then it would still be within the namespace of the class and callable by all other methods of the class, when it is really only useful for *that* particular method. So, in Scala, you can instead define it locally inside the method:

```
// non tail-recursive
def length[A](ls: List[A]) = ls match {
  case Nil => 0
  case x :: xs => length(xs) + 1
}

//transformation to tail-recursive, Java-style:
def length[A](ls: List[A]) = lengthRec(ls, 0)

private def lengthRec[A](ls: List[A], len: Int) = ls match {
  case Nil => len
  case x :: xs => lengthRec(xs, len + 1)
}

//tail-recursive, Scala-style:
def length[A](ls: List[A]) = {
  //note: lengthRec is nested and thus can access `ls`, there is no need to pass it
  def lengthRec(len: Int) = ls match {
    case Nil => len
    case x :: xs => lengthRec(xs, len + 1)
  }

  lengthRec(ls, 0)
}
```

Now you might say, well I see the value in defining local functions inside methods, but what's the value in being able to define local functions in blocks? Scala tries to as simple as possible and have as few corner cases as possible. If you can define local functions inside methods, and local functions inside local functions … then why not simplify that rule and just say that local functions behave just like local fields, you can simply define them in *any* block scope. Then you don't need different scope rules for local fields and local functions, and you have simplified the language.

The other thing you mentioned, being able to execute code in the bode of a template, that's actually the primary constructor (so to speak … it's technically more like an initializer). Remember: the primary constructor's signature is defined with parentheses after the class name … but where would you put the code for the constructor then? Well, you put it in the body of the class!

Comment: *method2 is actually not a method. It is a local function* The scope of the method is local, but as for what the compiler emits, that definitely looks like a method. Although the local function use-case is definitely handy, I'm not sure this is what OP was aiming for.

Comment: The compiler isn't emitting Scala, it is emitting JVM bytecode. The JVM doesn't have local functions, so the only thing the compiler could *possibly* emit is a method. The compiler isn't emitting `object`s or `trait`s either, but that doesn't mean that they don't exist. Hey, the Scala-native compiler only emits `GOTO`s, does that mean that there are no methods, `if`s and `match`es either?

Comment: The compiler will *eventually* emit JVM byecode though. The compilation process will go through phases we can peak at to understand the structure of code better. But saying the compiler transforms a method into a function? I don't know, but I feel since theres a clear distinction between the two in Scala that saying that isn't right. Of course we can go on about GOTOs and if elses, but then perhaps we should make a clear distinction between user level code and compiler emitted bytecode, since we can argue all of this is just plain machine code eventually anyway.

Comment: How the compiler chooses to encode a certain Scala construct is a private internal implementation detail of the compiler. Sure, the Scala-JVM compiler may encode a local function as a method in its target language. But I can assure you that the Scala-native compiler does *not* encode local functions as methods in *its* target language because its target language doesn't even *have* a notion of "method". On the other hand, the Scala.js compiler encodes methods as functions because that's what *its* target language has. So, as you can see, your assertion that "that's what the compiler does" …

Comment: Fair enough, I see what you mean.

Comment: Thanks ! This answer was helpful too.